# Accessing Query Variables inside inside dataIdFromObject in InMemoryCache?

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

I want to access the query variables to set the key in local cache, since my query doesn't have id and identical by query variable, how to access the query variables ?

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  dataIdFromObject: (object, variables) => {
    console.log(object, variables);
    switch (object.__typename) {
      default:
        return defaultDataIdFromObject(object); // fall back to default handling
    }
  },
});
```

In the above code variables is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Well it feels like. You need to do it on the backend.

```
query someQuery(justAnArg: Int) {
  someQuery {
    _justAnArg: $justAnArg
  }
}
```

This should do it.